# How to remove free spaces between divs

Tags: html, css

I have four divs, one under other, and I do not want the spaces between them. I tried to write some margins and paddings and nothing works. There are no borders so I don't know what makes the gaps between divs.

```css
.logo {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 125px;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.nav {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.picture {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}

.aboutus {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="logo">

    <p>logo</p>

  </div>


  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="main"><a href="main.html">Domov</a></li>
      <li class="gallery"><a class="active" href="gallery.html">Galéria</a></li>
      <li class="contacts"><a href="contacts.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="picture">

    <h1>picture</h1>

  </div>


  <div class="aboutus">

    <h1>about us</h1>

  </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On first glance, the `h1` tags are adding space so try this:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can also set the divs to `overflow: auto;` which is prefered if you want to keep your spacing above the `h1` tags

```
.nav, .picture, .aboutus {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Read more about collapsing margins here: [Collapsing margins](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/)

Answer (score -1):

The space is caused by h1's margin. The following line of code will fix it.

```
  h1
  {
    margin-top:0;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kwb0ygmd/

Answer (score -2):

you need to remove default margin from h1 and ul tags

```
h1, ul{
   margin: 0;
}
```

or you can use reset like https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```css
.logo {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 125px;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.nav {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.picture {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}

.aboutus {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
h1, ul{
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="logo">

    <p>logo</p>

  </div>


  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="main"><a href="main.html">Domov</a></li>
      <li class="gallery"><a class="active" href="gallery.html">Galéria</a></li>
      <li class="contacts"><a href="contacts.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="picture">

    <h1>picture</h1>

  </div>


  <div class="aboutus">

    <h1>about us</h1>

  </div>



</body>
```